# Interpret raw image data from Android Camera onPictureTaken(byte[] data)

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, camera

I'm using the Camera class to take a picture and want to do some processing on the image inside onPictureTaken.  How can I interpret the byte array?  Is it in RGB format or something else?

Answer (score 1):

References say it depends on Camera.Parameters ([Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html)), and in this post ([Re: FileOutPutstream code from onPictureTaken](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg04461.html)) they say that you must use the jpeg callback, so I guess it's jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

`mCamera.takePicture(null, null,mPictureCallbackRaw);`

where `mPictureCallbackRaw` is the instance of `Camera.PictureCallback`