# Image format of the camera (Android)

Tags: android, image, camera, histogram

Is there any way to get an image from the camera, and then your bitmap, which is not in any compressed format such as "jpeg"?.
The problem is that I need to calculate the histogram of an image, and if It's a format compressed the histograms are bit distorted.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351306/interpret-raw-image-data-from-android-camera-onpicturetakenbyte-data) help?

Comment: Thxx, but i can't take the raw image because the byte array is null :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function can only be done with HTC mobiles because of the camera.